# Outer arc length of a circle intersecting a circle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, plane-geometry, arc-length

Let $A$ be a circle of radius $r$, and let $B$ be a circle of radius $2r-\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon>0$, centered at a point on $A$.

How can one determine the outer arc of $A$ determined by where $B$ cuts $A$?

In the picture, I would like to determine the length of the outer green arc at the top of $A$.

I searched around and found similar questions, but none that matched what I am looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trigonometric approach:

Let's assume $X$ and $Y$ are the intersections of the circles $A$ and $B$, and $O$ and $Z$ are the centers of the circle $A$ and $B$, respectively. Consider $\triangle XOZ$ and $\triangle YOZ$, which are  **congruent isosceles triangles**. Thus,

$$\angle XOZ =\angle YOZ =2 \arcsin \frac{r-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{r} \implies \angle YOX =2\pi -4 \arcsin \frac{r-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{r}.$$

Now, you can determine the length of the desired arc.

---

[image]

Comment: Isn't $\angle XOZ=\pi-2 \arcsin \frac{r-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{r}$?

Comment: @Vasili Hi. If that was correct, for a small $\epsilon$, $\angle XOZ$ would approach zero ...

Comment: You are correct. My apologies.